# Focus on jQuery Mobile pageshow event not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I have a multipage HTML.  On page one is a link to a search page where I would like to automatically focus the text box for the search bar.

In my current code, it seems like some animations are lagging behind the `pageshow` event and don't technically appear until after the event fires.

I have the following javascript defined externally and in the body and i get the same result with either

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role="page"]', function (event) {
   $('#footerBagCount').text(myBag.totalQty);

   switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
       case "mpos":
           break;
       case "productlookup":
           $("input:text:visible:first").focus();
           $(document).enhanceWithin();
           break;
       default:
           console && console.log("default show!!");
   };
   console && console.log($(this).attr('id') + " - pageshow!!");
});
```

When this runs the textbox is not focused.  However if I go back and then to the search page again it appears.  It also appears if an alert window is called right after it.

I tried to reproduce the issue with a jsfiddle however was unsuccessful and it only shows the desired effect.
https://jsfiddle.net/PolishVendetta/az3kfh5y/

Are there any known issues that would cause this type of behavior?

**Edit**
I was able to replicate the issue and narrow down the cause.  I have panels defined outside of `page` to be used as external panels.  It looks like having a left panel defined like this works, however having a right side panel stops the highlight from displaying.

https://jsfiddle.net/PolishVendetta/cfu8g331/

Comment: Your fiddle causes the input field to be focused at the end of the fades for me.  I'm using Chrome.  That or I am not understanding your question.

Comment: as I said above, I have been unable to reproduce in a shorthand way.  The fiddle was an attempt to reproduce without adding every asset I'm using.

Comment: Unfortunately without a working example of the issue it is very difficult to diagnose.

Comment: Thats understood, I was hoping more that someone would recognize the behavior rather then find an error in the code.

Comment: Do you have other text input in pages visited before navigating to search page? If yes, be specific in target text input, `$("input", this)`. `this` is the page where `pageshow` is triggered. Btw, `pageshow` is deprecated and replaced with `pagecontainershow`. `.enhanceWithin()` is useful here, remove it.

Comment: For whatever reason `pagecontainershow` does not get triggered in the jsfiddle.  I did remove the `.enhanceWithin()`.

Comment: @PolishVendetta because `pagecontainershow` can't be attached to a specific page. It gets triggered on `document`.

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/cfu8g331/1/

Comment: @Omar this worked perfectly, if you have time i would love to see a little about what i was doing wrong.  At least provide some answer so I can say my question was answered.

Comment: Well, I just used a proper jQM event `pagecontainershow` and targeted a specific element within the current page. You can write an answer yourself now ;)

Comment: [`pageshow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pageshow) is deprecated because it's a native event. While `pagecontainershow` is a custom jQM event, which is emitted when page is fully loaded and transition/animation had finished. Always use jQM events jqmtricks.wordpress.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `pageshow` is deprecated because it's a native event. While
>   `pagecontainershow` is a custom jQM event, which is emitted when page
>   is fully loaded and transition/animation had finished.
>
> Always use jQM events

I changed this

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '[data-role="page"]', function(event) {
    switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
        case "mpos":
            break;
        case "productlookup":
            $("input:text:visible:first").focus();
            break;
        default:
            console && console.log("default show!!");
    };
    console && console.log($(this).attr('id') + " - pageshow!!");
});
```

To this

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (event, data) {
    var page = data.toPage;
    switch (page.prop('id')) {
        case "mpos":
            break;
        case "productlookup":
            $("input", page).focus();
            break;
        default:
            console && console.log("default show!!");
    };
    console && console.log(page.prop('id') + " - page container show!!");
});
```

Omar's jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cfu8g331/1/